# How to take average of Double[] in java

Tags: java, java-8

I have a map like following

```
Map<String, Double[]> userVecs;
userVecs.put("foo", [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]);
userVecs.put("bar", [0, 4, 2]);
```

I want an average vec which in this case is:

```
[1.1+0, 2.2+4, 3.3+2] / 2;


= [0.55, 3.1, 2.65]
```

I have an ugly two loop approach. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Is it guaranteed, that arrays in different entries always have the same length?

Comment: its guaranteed to be same length.

Comment: `[1.1+0, 2.2+4, 3.3+2] / 2` - can you please specify what should be the result, an array `Double[]`? Arrays are of equal length? If you share your code, it'll add more context to the problem.

Comment: I updated the post.. the answer should be `[0.55, 3.1, 2.65]` just an element-wise average. (like element-wise vector average)

Comment: If you have a solution, can you add it to your question?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using `Double[]` instead of `double[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way. It presumes the arrays are all the same length.

- declare a `sum` array of the proper length.
- iterate over the map values and add them via `Arrays.setAll()`
- then find the average using `userVecs.size()` and `Arrays.setAll()`

```
Map<String, double[]> userVecs = new HashMap<>();;
userVecs.put("foo", new double[]{1.1, 2.2, 3.3});
userVecs.put("bar", new double[]{0, 4, 2});

double[] sums = new double[userVecs.get("foo").length];

for (double[] dar : userVecs.values()) {
     Arrays.setAll(sums, i->sums[i]+dar[i]);
}

Arrays.setAll(sums, i->sums[i]/userVecs.size());

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sums));
```

prints

```
[0.55, 3.1, 2.65]
```

The [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) class has many useful features you may want to get familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to use an external Math library, you're gonna wanna just write the extra function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] arr1 = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
    double[] arr2 = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    double[] avg = elementWiseAvg(arr1, arr2);
}

public static double[] elementWiseAvg(double[] arr1, double[] arr2) {
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arrays must be the same length.");
    }
    double[] ret = new double[arr1.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
        ret[i] = (arr1[i] + arr2[i]) / 2;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a two-loop approach, but that's not necessarily ugly.  What you are effectively doing is summing two matrices of a single dimension.  Like was pointed out in another answer unless you want to import a math library, you're going to have to roll your own.

If you would like to explore an external library, look to jblas, it's a linear algebra library for Java.  Here's an example of summing and averaging those two vectors using jblas.

```
DoubleMatrix matrix1 = new DoubleMatrix(3, 1, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3);
DoubleMatrix matrix2 = new DoubleMatrix(3, 1, 0, 4, 2);

DoubleMatrix sum = matrix1.addColumnVector(matrix2).div(2);

log.info(sum);
```

The output is `[0.550000; 3.100000; 2.650000]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with Java 8 Streams.

The approach is to create a stream over the values of the given map, i.e. a stream of arrays `Double[]`. Then inside a *collector*, created using `Collector.of()` sum up array values for every index and as a final step divide each the value at each index by the map size.

In order to preserve arrays in the source map intact, we need to find out the length of these array and collect the data into a newly created array.

```
public static Double[] getAverage(Map<String, Double[]> userVecs) {
    if (userVecs.isEmpty()) {
        return new Double[0]; // throw an exception depending on your needs
    }
    
    int size = userVecs.values().iterator().next().length; // the map is proved to be non-empty, we can safely access one of its elements to find out the size of the resulting array
    
    return userVecs.values().stream()
        .collect(Collector.of(
            () -> Stream.generate(() -> 0d).limit(size).toArray(Double[]::new), // mutable container
            (Double[] res, Double[] next) -> mergeArrays(res, next),            // accumulator - populating the container
            (left, right) -> mergeArrays(left, right),                          // combiner - merging containers while executing in parallel
            res -> toAverage(res, userVecs.size())                              // finisher - transforming the container into a final result
        ));
}

public static Double[] mergeArrays(Double[] res, Double[] next) {
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) res[i] += next[i];
    return res;
}

public static Double[] toAverage(Double[] res, int mapSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) res[i] /= mapSize;
    return res;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Double[]> userVecs = new HashMap<>();
    
    userVecs.put("foo", new Double[]{1.1, 2.2, 3.3});
    userVecs.put("bar", new Double[]{0d, 4d, 2d});

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getAverage(userVecs)));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[0.55, 3.1, 2.65]
```